# next js mapping with-portals

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm looping through JSON data to create a grid of cards, clicking on a card will open a modal using portals. I used the Zeit example - https://github.com/zeit/next.js/tree/master/examples/with-portals

My map loop works for the cards, they are displaying as expected, but whatever card is clicked on, the data in the modal is always for the last card in the JSON file.

```
  { activities.map(activity => (
        <div key={activity.id}>
          <div className="grid-item" onClick={event => setOpen(true)}>
            <div className="card">
              <div className="card-image" style={{background: 'url(' + activity.image + ')'}}></div>
              <div className="card-content">
                <h2>{activity.name}</h2>
                <div className="card-footer">
                  <div className="age-range">{activity.ageFrom + ' - ' + activity.ageTo + ' yrs'}</div>
                  <div className="location">{activity.city}</div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          {open && (
            <ClientOnlyPortal selector="#modal">
              <div className="backdrop">
                <div className="modal">
                  <button type="button" onClick={event => setOpen(false)}>Close</button>
                  <Details 
                    id={activity.id}
                    name={activity.name}
                    website={activity.website}
                    category={activity.category}
                    image={activity.image}
                    image={activity.longDesc}
                  />
                </div>
              </div>
            </ClientOnlyPortal>
          )}
        </div>
      )
    )
  }
```

Comment: There is no need to map modal component multiple times. Maybe you can try to add it at the bottom of your render return.

Comment: ok thanks, that makes sense, my challenge then will be getting the details of the card clicked on into the modal. Any tips?!